# Print a document with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing, sharepoint-2010

I want to open a print dialog for a **file**(docx,pdf,...) via a SharePoint Workflow. There I call a URL with GET and pass the URL of the file after the ? like this:

> http://www.sharepoint_intranet.com/print.html?link-to-file.pdf

EDIT: I also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Get the URL of the file
    var urlOfFile = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    document.write("<iframe id=" + "printDocument" + " src=" + "'" + urlOfFile + "'" + " width=" + "600" + " height=" + "400" + "></iframe>");

    window.frames['printDocument'].focus();
    window.frames['printDocument'].print();

</script>
```

The Print Dialog is opening and in the print options there is the Point "Only selected Frame" selected but when I press the print button nothing will happen.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the new url doesn't start loading until the current script block has finished executing. Therefore when you call `w.print()`, the new window is currently blank.

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Get the URL of the file
    var urlOfFile = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    //print
    var w = window.open(urlOfFile);
    w.onload = function() {
        w.print();
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: I didn't read the question properly! The above technique only works for html. The way to solve this is to use an iframe and if we are using an iframe we might as well dispense with the popups entirely. The following code creates an iframe with a source set to the desired document, attaches the iframe to the page (but keeps it invisible), prints the contents of the iframe and finally removes the iframe once we've finished with it. Only tested in Chrome but I'm fairly confident that it'll work in other browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Get the URL of the file
    var urlOfFile = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    //print
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = urlOfFile;
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    var iFrameLoaded = function() {
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
        iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    };
    if (iframe.attachEvent) iframe.attachEvent('onload', iFrameLoaded); // for IE
    else if(iframe.addEventListener) iframe.addEventListener('load', iFrameLoaded, false); // for most other browsers
    else iframe.onload = iFrameLoaded; // just in case there's a browser not covered by the first two
    window.onload = function() {
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: it opens the file, but there is no print dialog

Comment: When I tried it on my computer (in Chrome) it also failed but that turned out to be the popup blocker. Allowing the popups on an individual basis didn't work as there were not allowed by the time onload was executed. The solution was to set the popup blocker to always allow popups from the domain. Maybe your issue is similar? Clearly that still leaves the task of educating your users - but you're always going to run into these sorts of issues with popups

Comment: I turned out the blocker but there is still no print Dialog (IE10 and FF21). For a empty site it works fine but for documents not...

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read your question properly and didn't notice you were printing pdfs. The approach I've used so far will only work for html. However, I believe you can solve the issue with an iframe. I'll modify my answer accordingly

Comment: for Chrome it works fine but not for ie(is used in Company, so it should work for it) and ff

Comment: I've now modified the code to try to make it more cross-browser friendly. However, I can't actually test it in anything other than Chrome on my machine - let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

you can put in the body of the html

```
<body onLoad="window.print();">
```

so the page is opened already prints the document.

Answer (score -1):

where we can give the path of the file like("abc.doc"/"abc.xls")

var urlOfFile = window.location.search.replace("?", "");